# HTML/JavaScript submission causing number to disappear

Tags: javascript, submit, nan

I have a form which requests a number and computes some additional numbers in JavaScript.  This is what it looks like after the JavaScript computation.

[image]

After I submit the form, the credit card processing fee becomes NaN, and the original form now looks like this:

[image]

That causes an error in the program I submitted to:

[image]

I have tried all sorts of ways to convince JavaScript that *strcustchg* is in fact a number.  I've used Number() and parseFloat() and +.  None of them help.  Here is the JavaScript code:

```javascript
function overcharge(evpct) {
  document.getElementById('idowe').innerHTML = '';
  var owed  = document.getElementById('owed').value;
  var offer = document.getElementById('amount').value;

  if (+offer > +owed) {
     document.getElementById('idowe').innerHTML = 'you cannot pay more than you owe';
  }
  if (+offer <= +owed) {
     var totchg      = (+offer + .30)/(1-.029);
     var strcustchg  = (totchg - offer)*evpct/100;
     strcustchgx     = strcustchg.toFixed(2);
     strcustchg      = (1.00)*strcustchg;
     totchg          = totchg.toFixed(2);

     document.getElementById('stripecharge').value = strcustchg;
     document.getElementById('totchg').value       = totchg;
  }
```

And here is the code that the JavaScript code targets:

```html
<td> Membership Fee<br>(including omitted payments)</td>
<td>
   <cfset mfee = NumberFormat(subtot,'9.99')>
   <input type  = 'text'
        class   = 'inp'
        readonly
        style   = 'background-color:##d8ebeb'
        name    = 'owed'
        id      = 'owed'
        style   = 'vertical-align:middle'
        value   = '#mfee#'>
 </td>
 <tr>
 <td> Amount You Will Pay</td>
 <td>
   <input type   = 'text'
        class    = 'inp'
        name     = 'amount'
        id       = 'amount'
        value    = '0'
        onchange = "overcharge('#evpct#')">
     <div class  = 'valida' id = 'idowe' ondoubleclick = "clearit('idowe')"></div>
 </td>
 <tr>
 <td> Credit Card<br>Processing Fee</td>
 <td>
   <input type   = 'text'
        class    = 'inp'
        readonly
        style    = 'background-color:##d8ebeb'
        id       = 'stripecharge'
        name     = 'strcustchg'
        style    = 'vertical-align:middle'
        value    = ''>
```

I can work around this problem after the submit, but I'd like to understand what is going on.  It seems as if the JavaScript shuts off after the submit, but that doesn't explain why the total cost on the screen is still showing correctly after the submission.  It also doesn't explain why a similar JavaScript program is running just fine. What is wrong here?

Comment: You're passing the string `#evpct#` as the argument to `overcharge()`. That's not a number, so you can't use it in the expression `(totchg - offer)*evpct/100`. It's not clear what you intend that to be.

Comment: Why is evpct not a number.  It is set to 100 in my application?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76376445/edit). (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today)

Comment: Hi, I did locate the problem, and it is not a exactly coding error.  The form shows target = '_blank', which opens a new tab.  So when the submit occurs, the program reruns the javascript with blank input, resulting in the NaN.   It's good to know this about how the new tab feature works.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I was unable to figure out what changes you made.  I do want to submit as clearly and concisely as possible.  I looked at the "do the right thing" page but still couldn't see what the changes are.  Thanks for your help.